# How to change background-color on text links on hover but not image links

Tags: css

I have a CSS rule like this:

```
a:hover { background-color: #fff; }
```

But this results in a bad-looking gap at the bottom on image links, and what's even worse, if I have transparent images, the link's background color can be seen through the image.

I have stumbled upon this problem many times before, but I always solved it using the quick-and-dirty approach of assigning a class to image links:

```
a.imagelink:hover { background-color: transparent; }
```

Today I was looking for a more elegant solution to this problem when I stumbled upon [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images%2c_Tables%2c_and_Mysterious_Gaps).

Basically what it suggests is using `display: block`, and this really solves the problem for non-transparent images. However, it results in another problem: now the link is as wide as the paragraph, although the image is not.

Is there a nice way to solve this problem, or do I have to use the dirty approach again?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to find some selector that would get only `<a>` elements that don't have `<img>` descendants, but couldn't find any...
About images with that bottom gap, you could do the following:

```
a img{vertical-align:text-bottom;}
```

This should get rid of the background showing up behind the image, but may throw off the layout (by not much, though), so be careful.

For the transparent images, you should use a class.

I really hope that's solved in CSS3, by implementing a parent selector.

Comment: This solves the OP's problem, but is not the answers to the OP's title

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused at what you are terming "image links"... is that an 'img' tag inside of an anchor? Or are you setting the image in CSS?

If you're setting the image in CSS, then there is no problem here (since you're already able to target it)... so I must assume you mean:

```
<a ...><img src="..." /></a>
```

To which, I would suggest that you specify a background color on the image... So, assuming the container it's in *should* be white...

```
a:hover { background: SomeColor }
a:hover img { background-color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like this to remove the gap under images:

```
img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Of course this is not always the ideal solution but it's fine in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

This way works way better.

```
a[href$=jpg], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=jpe], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif] {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0 none;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
```

No cumbersome classes that have to be applied to each image. Detailed description here:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/10/14/css-remove-link-underlines-borders-linked-images/

Answer (score 1):

Untested idea:

```
a:hover {background-color: #fff;}
img:hover { background-color: transparent;}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work since I'm not changing the background color of the image, but that of the link.

Comment: plus i don't think IE supports the pseudo-classes on anything but links.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (untested):

First you

```
 a:hover { background-color: #fff; }
```

Then you

```
a:imagelink:hover { background-color: inherit; }
```

The second rule will override the first for <a class="imagelink" etc.> and preserve the background color of the parent.

I tried to do this without the class="", but I can't find a CSS selector that is the opposite of foo > bar, which styles a bar when it is the child of a foo. You would want to style the foo when it *has* a child of class bar. You can do that and even fancier things with jQuery, but that may not be desirable as a general technique.

Comment: I guess it should be a.imagelink:hover {  background-color: inherit;   }

Answer (score 0):

you could use display: inline-block but that's not completely crossbrowser. IE6 and lower will have a problem with it.

I assume you have whitespaces between `<a>` and `<img>`? try removing that like this:

`<a><img /></a>`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, and used another solution than `display: block` thanks to the link by asker. This means I am able to retain the link **ONLY** on the image and not expand it to its container.

Images are inline, so they have space below them for lower part of letters like "y, j, g". This positions the images at `baseline`, but you can alter it if you have no `<a>TEXT HERE</a>` like with a **logo**. However you still need to mask the text line space and its easy if you use a plain color as background (eg in `body` or `div#wrapper`).

```
body {
  background-color: #112233; 
}
a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
a img {
  border-style: none; /* not need for this solution, but removes borders around images which have a link */
  vertical-align: bottom; /* here */
}
a:hover img {
  background-color: #112233; /* MUST match the container background, or you arent masking the hover effect */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I am using the image as background. I did the following and it resolved my problem:

```
background-image: url(file:"use the same background image or color");
```