# How to remove :hover background from this linked image?

Tags: html, css, hover

in the right sidebar [here](http://glamourina.pl), if you go hover the DMCA image, you can see that a black background appears.

I am struggling, because I can't remove it, without removing the whole`.aboutmesection a:hover{background-color:#000;color:#FFD700;}`, but I don't want to.
I just want to remove what's appearing under this transparent image.

I have also tried to apply [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273964/how-to-change-background-color-on-text-links-on-hover-but-not-image-links), but don't seem to work in this specific case.

Does anybody know how the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Give it an id and specific styling ?

Comment: I'd like to avoid giving specific ids to all the images that will be added there in future. If it is technically possible I'd like it to work like this for all the images inside the `.sidebar' class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a more specific selector to overwrite the rule with one that does not change the background on hover, f.e.

```
.aboutmesection .divaligncenter:last-child a:hover {
  background:none;
}
```

(`:last-child` because you have two divs `.divaligncenter` in `.aboutmesection`)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked. So if I rename the class name of this div, I can remove `:last-child`, right?

Comment: Yes. Or just add another class, if you want to keep the formatting effects of the existing one.