# Change background-color on text links but not image links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

I have an issue, I would like my text link to have a `background-color` on `:hover` but now, the divs and images which are linked also have this `background-color`, does anyone has an idea how i can apply this `background-color` only to the text links?

I have tried all sorts of codes :

```
a:hover img{
   background-color: transparent;
}

a img:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

but nothing has worked...

This is not a duplicated of the linked question, I can't put a class on some links or images because it's running on wordpress so I can't programm all text links or all image links to have a certain class.

I have tried the "vertical align" solution of 
[How to change background-color on text links on hover but not image links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273964/how-to-change-background-color-on-text-links-on-hover-but-not-image-links), but i have images with padding, so one can see the background around, and also on regular image, one can see a thin yellow line aswell.

Comment: Can you provide us with example of your html?

Comment: Please could you provide an example, it's a fairly open question. First thought is that you need to use some sort of selector. Perhaps the :not pseudo selector will help you in this case?

Comment: use a specific class on text links, and use it as a selector

Comment: @Apolo this is not possible because it is a shop powered by woocommerce, so i can't apply a class on all links (whether they are text or img).

Comment: @Paulie_D could you at least provide the link to the duplicate ?

Comment: Links at the top of the page.

Comment: @Paulie_D I edited and explained why the solution on the other post doesn't work and how my problem is different.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you are out of luck. I think you will find there is no other solution except perhaps javascript

Comment: @Paulie_D what could be that solution? Do a javascript to search for all text link and add a class to them?